# Removing slashes from dates within a data.frame

Tags: string, r, date, dataframe

I have a series of dates within a data.frame of the form x <- data.frame(01/01/2009). I would like to change the series to be of the form 01012009. I have tried the gsub("//","" x) but it does not appear to work.

I would just like to remove the <strike>back</strike> forward slashes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are only forward slashes in your example - no backslashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to escape a forward slash (which is not what you are doing anyway), so this will work, e.g:

```
dat <- data.frame(dates=c("01/01/2009","02/01/2009"))
dat
#       dates
#1 01/01/2009
#2 02/01/2009

dat$dates <- gsub("/","",dat$dates)
dat
#     dates
#1 01012009
#2 02012009
```

Comment: Thank you! I was wanting to apply this to an entire vector stored as a data.frame rather an individual input. Is there a way to modify this to do that?

Comment: @user2832896 - `gsub` will work just the same on a single value as it will on a vector in a data.frame. See my edits.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach is to use `as.Date` / `strftime` and other date time manipulation functions in R

```
# create a Date column (can do things with dates as dates now)
dat$Date <- as.Date(as.character(dat$dates),format = '%d/%m/%Y')
# create character column with format of your desire
dat$newDate <- strftime(dat$Date, '%d%m%Y')
```